# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to

Tags: .net, oracle, odp.net

I'm invoking an Oracle function from a .NET application and I always get following exception:
  PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TF_GETNODES'

Here is the definition of the Oracle function:

```
FUNCTION "IMPACTNET"."TF_GETNODES"
(
    DIMENSIONKEY  IN NVARCHAR2,
    PARENTNODE    IN NVARCHAR2,
    PARASTRING    IN NVARCHAR2
) RETURN IMPACTNET.TREE_NODE_TABLE IS

    treeNodes IMPACTNET.TREE_NODE_TABLE;

BEGIN

    treeNodes:=IMPACTNET.TREE_NODE_TABLE();
    for i in 1..2
    loop
    treeNodes.extend;
    treeNodes(i) := IMPACTNET.TREE_NODE(DIMENSIONKEY || i, PARENTNODE || i, 0, 0, PARASTRING || i, 0);
    end loop;

    RETURN treeNodes;

END;
```

And here is my .NET code:

```
var treeNodes = new TreeNodesTable();

using (var connection = CreateConnection())
using (var command = new OracleCommand { Connection = connection, CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure, CommandText = "IMPACTNET.TF_GETNODES" })
{
    command.Parameters.Add("DIMENSIONKEY", OracleDbType.NVarchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = "dimension key";
    command.Parameters.Add("PARENTNODE",   OracleDbType.NVarchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = "parent node";
    command.Parameters.Add("PARASTRING",   OracleDbType.NVarchar2, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = "para string";

    var p1 = new OracleParameter
    {
        ParameterName = "treeNodes",
        OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Object,
        UdtTypeName = "IMPACTNET.TREE_NODE_TABLE",
        Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue,
        Value = treeNodes
    };
    command.Parameters.Add(p1);

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    treeNodes = (TreeNodesTable)p1.Value;
}
```

Comment: looks like this would help you out.  https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1090421

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like Allan I'm not an ODP expert.  However, I do know that Oracle stores the return value of a function as PARAMETER `0` in the Data Dictionary.  The input parameters are `1`, `2`, etc.

So, if you declare and assign the return value *before* you assign the input parameters it might work.

Comment: That's the reason! It works when I add the return value parameter as the very first one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on the .NET side of things, but it looks to me like you're setting up your UDT as a parameter, rather than as a return value. Try dropping your function and replacing it with the following procedure:

```
PROCEDURE "IMPACTNET"."TF_GETNODES"
(
    DIMENSIONKEY  IN  NVARCHAR2,
    PARENTNODE    IN  NVARCHAR2,
    PARASTRING    IN  NVARCHAR2,
    treeNodes     OUT IMPACTNET.TREE_NODE_TABLE
) IS
BEGIN
    treeNodes:=IMPACTNET.TREE_NODE_TABLE();
    for i in 1..2 loop
       treeNodes.extend;
       treeNodes(i) := IMPACTNET.TREE_NODE(DIMENSIONKEY || i, 
                                           PARENTNODE || i, 
                                           0, 
                                           0, 
                                           PARASTRING || i, 
                                           0);
    end loop;
END;
/
```

If that works, you can either leave it as-is, or investigate how to get the return value back in the .NET call.