# Entity Framework + Stored Procedures = ERROR "PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to "

Tags: sql, oracle, entity-framework

I'm trying to get Entity to use Oracle Stored Procedures. I'm getting the same error with two different Stored procedures.

I've been able to setup the columns in the App.Config file so they appear when I "Add Function Import.." but when I try to access the entity context I get the below error

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
>   PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'RISK_GETALLCHANNELS'

The Procedure is pretty basic:

```
    PROCEDURE       "RISK_GETALLCHANNELS" (p_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    IS 
    BEGIN
    OPEN p_cursor FOR
    SELECT r.ChannelId, r.Name, CASE WHEN r.active = 1 THEN 'Active' ELSE 'InActive'       END AS "Active", r.domain
    FROM risk_channel r;
    END Risk_GetAllChannels;
```

This has been driving me crazy so any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040115/pls-00306-wrong-number-or-types-of-arguments-in-call-to

Comment: Similar question but I believe it's different. I'm using Entity rather than creating a connection and adding the parameters.

Comment: @Brenton, were you able to solve this?

Comment: @Brenton, can you paste the app.config code also?

Comment: No we ended up solving it a different way and the app.config has changed quite a bit since the question was posted.